# Modifying iframe in chrome with disabled CORS security

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, security, cors

I've installed 74 Chrome (since in latest chrome disabling security does not work) and run it with disabling cors security flags:

`open -a "Google Chrome 74" --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/Users/Victor/GoogleTmp"`

Chrome has notified me that security is disabled. I've successfully run cross-domain ajax request.

Now, I have an iframe and I need to modify its styles. I googled that I can insert a link tag in order to do that. But even though the security is disabled I got the following error:

`SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:5555" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

I also tried other different methods, like nginx proxy pass etc, none of them worked. But I wonder why disabling web security doesn't help?

Here is sample code for inserting css (I use vuejs)

```
 let cssLink = document.createElement("link")
 cssLink.href = "style.css"
 cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"
 cssLink.type = "text/css"

 const iframe = this.$refs.vizContainer.firstChild

 this.$refs.vizContainer.firstChild.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(cssLink)
```

Comment: are you using any backend framework ?

Comment: can you access the other iframe source and add extra javascript code?

Answer (score -1):

You can't allow from clientside code as anyone can change it. YOu need to allow on ngnx or openlitespeed whatsoever.

`Header unset X-Frame-Options Header unset Content-Security-Policy`

normally it should be like this:

`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 X-Frame-Options: Deny Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none' X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`

To configure the headers `X-Frame-Options` and `Content-Security-Policy` on Nginx or OpenLiteSpeed, you can modify the server configuration file. Here's how you can achieve it:

For Nginx:

1. Locate the Nginx configuration file. By default, the main configuration file is usually located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
2. Open the configuration file in a text editor.
3. Inside the `http` block, add or modify the `server` block to include the desired headers. Here's an example:

   ```
   http {
     ...
     server {
       ...
       location / {
         ...
         add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
         add_header X-Frame-Options "Deny";
         add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'none'";
         add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
         ...
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   In this example, the `add_header` directive is used to set the desired headers and their corresponding values.
4. Save the configuration file.
5. Restart Nginx to apply the changes. The command to restart Nginx varies based on the operating system and how it was installed. For example, you can use the following command on Ubuntu:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart nginx
   ```

For OpenLiteSpeed:

1. Locate the server configuration file for OpenLiteSpeed. By default, the configuration file is usually located at `/usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf`.
2. Open the configuration file in a text editor.
3. Inside the `<VirtualHost>` block corresponding to the domain or specific website, add or modify the `header` directives to include the desired headers. Here's an example:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ...
       ServerName example.com
       ...

       header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
       header set X-Frame-Options "Deny"
       header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'none'"
       header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
       ...
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   The `header` directive is used to set the desired headers and their corresponding values.
4. Save the configuration file.
5. Restart or reload OpenLiteSpeed to apply the changes. The command to restart OpenLiteSpeed varies based on the operating system and how it was installed. For example, you can use the following command on Ubuntu:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart lsws
   ```

With these configurations, the headers `Strict-Transport-Security`, `X-Frame-Options`, `Content-Security-Policy`, and `X-Content-Type-Options` will be set according to the specified values. Adjust the configuration files and values based on your specific requirements.

Note: Modifying server configuration files requires proper access and permissions. Ensure you have the necessary privileges or consult with your server administrator if needed.

Comment: None of these headers will allow JS to access the DOM of an iframe across origins.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question is CORS enabled iframe

Comment: There’s no such thing as a CORS enabled iframe.

Comment: There is actually. Websites block their usage

Comment: CORS is a standard to allow access to resources where they would *normally* be blocked by the Same Origin Policy. The Same Origin Policy forbids accessing an iframe across origins. CORS has no features which would allow that particular part of the Same Origin Policy to be relaxed hence there is no such thing as a CORS enabled iframe.